# Local user creation from shell for Ambari and Hue - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, administration, hue

I've been using Ambari and Hue to manage my hadoop cluster for some weeks, but I haven't found any option/command/code/tool to create local users for both from the shell (Neither in their REST APIs).

I know both use mysql/sqlite databases to store their users (I'm able to access both tables), and I was tracing the code to see in which part they add user to the database, without success.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use something similar to http://gethue.com/password-management-in-hue/ and
https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/apps/useradmin/src/useradmin/views.py#L163

`user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username='bob')`

Then do a get_profile(instance) to make sure the user is fully configured.

The other way would be to do a POST request with curl or another lib with the Hue cookie of an admin user:

`http://hue:8000/useradmin/users/new`

With this parameters:

```
username:bob
password1:test
password2:test
ensure_home_directory:on
first_name:
last_name:
email:
groups:1
is_active:on
```

gethue.com has an upcoming blog post about this!